# how to open .mdb from ftp location jackcess

Tags: java, database, ftp, sharing, jackcess

hi all with this code i can successfully download allpg.mdb and displaying...
now i want to save the downloaded file to c:/folder....

if i edit

```
dbTempFile = File.createTempFile("dbTempFile",".mdb");   to
dbTempFile = File.createTempFile("c:/dbTempFile",".mdb"); than it give : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect error.
```

i just want to save the downloaded file to any where to my local drive.

here is code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Database;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Table;

public class DownloadFile {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

File dbTempFile=null; 
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

try {
  client.connect("ftp.mypak.com");
  client.login("myid", "mypwd");
  client.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

  dbTempFile = File.createTempFile("dbTempFile",".mdb");
  fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(dbTempFile);
  client.retrieveFile("/HASSAN/MDMSTATS/allpg.mdb", fileOutputStream);
} catch (IOException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  try {
    if (fileOutputStream != null) {
      fileOutputStream.close();
      System.out.println("got");





     Table table = Database.open(dbTempFile).getTable("items");
     System.out.println(table.display());

      System.out.println("got");
    }
    client.disconnect();
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not giving the right file name to the Jackcess constructor.  should be:

```
      Table table = Database.open(dbTempFile).getTable("items");
```

Comment: Table table = Database.open(dbTempFile).getTable("items"); it gives error:local variable dbTempFile may not have been initialized

Comment: @user2058260 - i would guess that you are corrupting the database.  please ensure that you are successfully downloading the file.  one common source of errors when using ftp is not using "binary" mode.

Comment: @jtahlborn- now code is working fine, can you tell me at which location this file is downloaded so i can access for further.

Comment: basically i want to download a csv file and than convert it with        Database.open(new File("c:/MDMSTATS/APEX/APEXCONV.mdb")).importFile("items", new File("c:/MDMSTATS/APEX/testreport_pakistan.csv"), ",");

Comment: so i need the location of the csv file to convert

Comment: got the location of downloaded file its in temp folder..but each time i run program it save the downloaded file with different name like "dbTempFile2069","dbTempFile3069"  i want to save this file each time with same name

Comment: this solves the problem no downloaded file will be saved @ project folder :)     File dbTempFile= new File("dbTempFile.csv");